# EmberJS change environment variables (e.g. rootURL) at runtime

Tags: ember.js

I need to change the environment variable rootURL at loading time, depending on some global js variable (_ENV), which denotes Symfony's current environment.

So, if accessing the app via http://somedomain.com/app/ it should be `rootURL = '/app/'`.
If accessing via http://somedomain/app_dev.php/app/ it should be `rootURL = '/app_dev.php/app/'`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to change environment.js variables at runtime, because they are for building an app. At runtime you can only access them. You may set them different for different environments - use app_dev for development and app for production, for example. And you don't need to change rootURL, you need to change adapter's config (host and prefix) depending on environment.